# Why UITextView scroll not working on tvOS?

Tags: swift, uitextview, tvos

I have `UITextView`:

```
    private let descriptionView: UITextView = {
       let view = UITextView()
       view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       view.bounces = true
       view.textColor = UIColor.white
       view.font = UIFont(name: Fonts.regular, size: 28)

       view.isSelectable = true
       view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
       view.panGestureRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UITouch.TouchType.indirect.rawValue)]
       view.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
       return view
    }()
```

Added in another view

```
    addSubview(descriptionView)
    addConstraints([
        descriptionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: title.leadingAnchor),
        descriptionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ratings.bottomAnchor, constant: 60),
        descriptionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -80),
        descriptionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
    ])
```

`isSelectable = true`,

`view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`.

View focuses great, but not scrolling.

Content height > textview height

[image]

Similar questions did't help

Comment: Maybe this will work for you -> `view.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`

Comment: Emre Ciftci, that property deprecated

Comment: Ooops I'm sorry for deprecated answer :) Please try this -> `view.isScrollEnabled = true`

Comment: I tried that, but didn't help(